# how to find values that are common for different fields [pymongo aggregate]

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

Let's say we have mongodb documents:

```
{'shop':'yes'}
{'shop':'ice_cream'}
{'shop':'grocery'}
{'amenity':'yes'}
{'amenity':'hotel'}
```

How do I write an aggregate query in pymongo which would return the values that are common for both keys? In that example it should return 'yes'.

Answer (score 3):

Your aggregation pipeline would make use of the [**`$setIntersection`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/) in the [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) operator stage. This takes two or more arrays and returns an array that contains the elements that appear in every input array. Another aggregation operator that is useful is the [**`$addToSet`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/#grp._S_addToSet) array operator which is used in creating the distinct list of values for each grouped field that can then be compared later on.

In mongoshell, inserting the documents

```
db.collection.insert([
    {'shop':'yes'},
    {'shop':'ice_cream'},
    {'shop':'grocery'},
    {'amenity':'yes'},
    {'amenity':'hotel'}
])
```

You could try the following aggregation pipeline:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "shops": {
                "$addToSet": "$shop"
            },
            "amenities": {
                "$addToSet": "$amenity"
            }
        }        
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "commonToBoth": { "$setIntersection": [ "$shops", "$amenities" ] }
        }
    }
]);
```

**Output**:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "commonToBoth" : [ 
                "yes"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

**Pymongo**:

```
>>> pipe = [
...     {"$group": { "_id": None, "shops": {"$addToSet": "$shop"}, "amenities": {"$addToSet": "$amenity"}}},
...     { "$project": {"_id": 0, "commonToBoth":{"$setIntersection": ["$shops", "$amenities"]}}}
...     ]
>>>
>>> for doc in collection.aggregate(pipe):
...     print(doc)
...
{u'commonToBoth': [u'yes']}
```